# "sinto muito" é uma figura de linguagem?"

Tags: figuras-de-linguagem

Algumas vezes quem diz "sinto muito" realmente lamenta alguma coisa.  Na maioria das vezes, contudo, tanto quem fala quanto o seu interlocutor sabem que ninguém lamenta coisa alguma, e usa "sinto muito" com o significado de "desculpe-me" que, por sua vez, também não é um pedido de desculpas. Exemplos:

- "Sinto muito, mas a senhora vai ter que acatar nossa decisão."
- "Sinto muito, mas o senhor não pode entrar por essa porta."
- "Não gostou? Sinto muito, mas é o que temos."
- "Sinto muito, João, mas tu tens que tirar o teu carro da frente do meu portão."
- "Sinto muito, mas o seu carro não está pronto."
- "Sinto muito, mas você mereceu."

Como classificar esse uso de "sinto muito"?  Uma figura de linguagem?  Qual?

Comment: As pessoas são capazes de sentir emoçoês fortes. Se uma pessoa se sente mal, isso é uma sensação ou emoção forte. Não creo que haja nemhum sentido figurado. Ou seja, "O que eu fiz, me fez sentir mal." Sinto muito. Tambem, essa expressões as vezes se viram clichés.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não classificaria este uso como figurativo, a não ser que o emissor esteja usando uma ironia:

> [Sinto muito ter incomodado você com minha beleza e inteligência, mas nem todos conseguem ser insignificantes.](https://www.frasesparaface.com.br/sinto-muito-ter-incomodado-voce-com-minha-beleza/)

Nos exemplos que você citou, eu não vejo o emprego desta expressão como linguagem figurada, mas como linguagem literal mesmo. O sentido que o emissor quis dar à expressão corresponde ao literal da mesma expressão.

O que talvez esteja lhe trazendo confusão seja o uso comum de uma expressão de desculpas quando o emissor não sente, de fato, arrependimento. Neste caso, o uso desta expressão representa um desvio ético (no sentido filosófico), mas não denotativo ao significado de *sinto muito*. O autor utiliza a expressão pelo seu valor político na resolução de conflitos, mesmo que ela não corresponda ao sentimento real do mesmo, para (dis)simular empatia pelo destinatário da mensagem:

> "Sinto muito, mas a senhora vai ter que acatar nossa decisão."

- *Sinto muito pelo incômodo que isto possa vir a lhe causar. Apesar disto, a senhora vai ter que acatar nossa decisão.*

> "Sinto muito, João, mas tu tens que tirar o teu carro da frente do meu portão."

- *Sinto muito que não haja outra possibilidade que não dependa de você, João, mas eu quero sair e o seu carro está me impedindo.*

> "Sinto muito, mas você mereceu."

- *Sinto muito que você só tenha sido capaz de aprender da forma mais difícil, mas isto não desfaz os danos que você causou, e agora você está sendo punido por isto.*

Enquanto expressão idiomática, *sinto muito* é comum porque o emissor não admite responsabilidade sobre o infortúnio, exime-se da necessidade de conceder explicações, e não pode ser provado do contrário (mesmo que o interlocutor saiba ser mentira, ele não dispõe dos meios para prová-la).

Comment: Em vários dos exemplos parece-me que "sinto muito" é usado pro forma. Creio que isso faz tambbém parde de "O autor utiliza a expressão pelo seu valor político na resolução de conflitos..." ?

Comment: Os exemplos que dei são aqueles em que a pessoa nada sente.  Em "Não gostou?  Sinto muito, mas é o que temos", o locutor não sente nada. O sinto muito é até irônico.

Comment: Não sendo uma figura de linguagem, seria uma figura de retórica?

Comment: @Jacinto Acredito que sim. Varia de personalidade para personalidade, mas me parece mais fácil emitir uma mensagem considerada desagradável para o interlocutor quando se começa com _sinto muito_.

Comment: @Centaurus É possível que seja irônico, mas também é possível que o emissor preferisse não estar na posição de ter de dizer "é o que temos". A diferença aqui estaria mais na questão mentira x linguagem figurada. Embora o autor da fala realmente não sinta nada, a mensagem que ele quer passar é a de que sente? Se sim, não entendo como uma figura de linguagem. Eu não saberia dizer se é uma figura de retórica, porque, a princípio, não me parece uma questão relacionada à linguagem, mas à ética (no sentido filosófico).

Comment: @RamonMelo   Nesses casos a entonação é que faz a diferença.  Eu tanto posso dizer "Não gostou?  Sinto muito mas não temos mais nada do gênero no momento." que soa mais educado, ou "Não gostou?  Sinto muito mas é o que temos." que soa como "não está satisfeito, procure em outro lugar."